# When I use group_by and summarise. my result got mix up?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I use function below, the result of summarise are not group up instead it mix together. How should I fix it?

```
dep %>%
 group_by(ORIGIN) %>%
  summarise(ontime_dep = sum(dep$DEP_TYPE == "ontime", na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data, and describe what you mean with "mix together"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution and let me please know.

```
dep %>%
 dplyr::group_by(ORIGIN) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(ontime_dep = sum(dep$DEP_TYPE == "ontime", na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Perfect. I guess you have loaded `plyr` package before. Therefore `dplyr::` should be kept in mind when things are strange.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided it seems like you want to count the number of departures that were on time, for every origin?

In this case you could simply use `count()`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    filter(gear == 3) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    count()
```